# Mapping Server site model to Client site model in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

My Server site C# model

```
 public  class Teacher:Entity
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
 }
```

Client site TypeScript model

```
export class Teacher extends Entity {
    public name:string;
    public address:string;
    public phoneNo :string;
}
```

client site service

```
getDataById(id: string):Observable<T> {
    return this.repo.get(this.subUrl+'query',id).map( (res)=>{ return <T> res.json()})
}
```

client site controller

```
this.subscription= this.techerService.getDataById(this.id).subscribe( (data:Teacher) =>{
       console.log(data);
       this.model.name=data.name;
       console.log(this.model))};
```

Output result: [Result on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3Iy.png)

Can I map this without this type of mapping?

```
this.model.name=data['Name'];
```

I want to map this approach or better approach

```
this.model.name=data.name;
```

**Please help**

Comment: use a TypeScript `interface`, not a `class`. In your backend, set `JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`

Comment: Solved this problem with  `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `Teacher` has a lower-case `name`. You receive an object with upper-case `Name`. TypeScript should complain that `data` has no `Name` member, so declare your `data` parameter as `any`, not as `Teacher`.

```
this.subscription= this.techerService.getDataById(this.id).subscribe((data:any) =>{
       console.log(data);
       this.model.name=data.Name;
       console.log(this.model);
```